# HTTPS Post failure

Tags: c#, post, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I´m trying to send a POST request to an API on my Xamarin Forms application and I´m getting an error that indicates that there is no trust relationship when sending the request. I cannot find out why is this and how to solve it. This is the exception:

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending
>   the request ---> System.Net.WebException: Error: TrustFailure (The
>   authentication or decryption has failed.) ---> System.IO.IOException:
>   The authentication or decryption has failed. --->
>   System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
>   ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: Invalid certificate received from server. Error code: 0xffffffff800b010f   at
>   Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndReceiveRecord
>   (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00031] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/RecordProtocol.cs:430
>   at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.SafeEndReceiveRecord
>   (System.IAsyncResult ar, System.Boolean ignoreEmpty) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/SslClientStream.cs:256
>   at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.NegotiateAsyncWorker
>   (System.IAsyncResult result) [0x00071] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/xamarin-android/xamarin-android/external/mono/mcs/class/Mono.Security/Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls/SslClientStream.cs:418
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

The code resulting in this exception is the following:

```
MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
content.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Token", "eb27c17f-8bd6-4b94-bc4f-742e361b4e6a");
content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/jpeg");

content.Add(new ByteArrayContent(myByteImage));

try
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.PostAsync("https://10.54.66.160:9000/3/matching/search?list_id=3c9f2623-28be-435f-a49f-4dc29c186809&limit=1", content);

    string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw;
}
```

Comment: are you using a self-signed certificate?

Comment: @DanielA.White yes the API has a self signed certificate

Comment: that likely is the issue. the device can't trust the self signed cert.

Comment: @DanielA.White is there any workaround for that? do i have to install another certificate type to the other service?

Comment: @DanielA.White I just solved the problem by adding some lines on MainActivity.cs. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

It seems the problem solved putting the following code on `MainActivity.cs`

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback +=
            (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
            {
                if (cert != null) System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(cert);
                return true;
            };
```

As @DanielA.White It seems that the mono implementation of HttpClient does not support self signed certificates.

Comment: In OnCreate - before LoadApplication method call?

Comment: i putting the following code on constructor of App.cs, thanks dear