# Handling response from API

Tags: c#, json, api, xamarin, task

I am trying to handle a response from an api, i keep getting a TLSException, and can't find any relevant informaton on this exception online.

I am posting a username and password to the server succesfully, but the exception occurs while trying to deserialize the response.

The response consists of 2 strings, and i made a class called Response, matching this. This is how i handle the response

```
public async Task<Response> PostResponse<Response>(string weburl, 
FormUrlEncodedContent content)
    {
        var response = await client.PostAsync(weburl, content);
        var jsonResult = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response> 
        (jsonResult);
        return responseObject;
    }
```

I followed a somewhat similar post and tried the code:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

I dont know if this is solving my problem as this arises a new exception:

```
Cannot Convert System.Func[SystemObject, SystemSecurity]
```

Comment: Show the full stack trace

Comment: Check version of Newtonsoft.Json in both projects and make sure are the same.

Comment: first try to open post Url in address bar of your browser and tell the result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could not establish trust relationship for SSL/TLS secure channel -- SOAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703272/could-not-establish-trust-relationship-for-ssl-tls-secure-channel-soap)

Comment: Is it correct to place the object that matches the response in the Task<>?

Comment: A TLS exception should have nothing to do with `Json.NET`, do you even get a `jsonResult`? Also why are you using `.Result` when you can await?

Comment: I am not sure if i even get a jsonresult, if i change the ip to something else the exception doesn't occur, so that tells me i am receiving atleast something?

Comment: TLS exception is not to do with deserialisation. TLS is Transport Layer Security, like HTTPS.

Comment: var jsonResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
like that?

Comment: @haim770 no stack trace, just a pop up from xamarin live on my device that says:

Uncaught Exception, Certificate Unknown(TlsException)

Comment: Yeah @SteveJ, could that mean that i don't authenticate to the server using my current username / password? It should be correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTPS Post failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48450290/https-post-failure)

Comment: Can someone answer me though, the Task<> should have the object that corresponds to the response right?

Comment: @Gustavbang not sure. I wouldn't have thought so. Can you query the API with a browser, PostMan or Fiddler? See if you get certificate errors doing that. Does the API endpoint start with http: or https:?

Comment: "the Task<> should have the object that corresponds to the response "...if you're getting a TLS Exception its failing long before you get any kind of response. It's not even making a valid connection to the server. Your client does not think the server's SSL certificate is valid.

Comment: I see, thanks for clarification! The connection is from Huawei and i know another programmer succeeded in connection, can something be done from client side to accept the certificate?

Comment: @TAHASULTANTEMURI When i try to open in my browser it says:
HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL
This tells me that the connection should be open.. I really dont know where to look for this error

Comment: Skip using Xamarin Live, deploy/debug directly on the device and add the Exception/Stacktrace to your question